# I get an error when I create a table including primary key and foreign key

Tags: mysql, database

I tried to create a table with primary and foreign key but it gives me an error saying

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),
projectLeader INT(3),
PRIMARY KEY (empNo, projNo),
FOREIGN KEY (empNo) REFERE' at line 4

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),
totalCharge DOUBLE(8),
PRIMARY KEY (empNo, jobClass),
FOREIGN KEY (empNo) REF' at line 4
```

the table codes that gets error messages are:

```
CREATE TABLE projectInfo(
    empNo INT(3) not null,
    projNo INT(2) not null,
    hourBill DOUBLE(4),
    projectLeader INT(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (empNo, projNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (empNo) REFERENCES employee (empNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (projNo) REFERENCES project (projNo)
);

CREATE TABLE workInfo(
    empNo INT(3) not null,
    jobClass VARCHAR(4) not null,
    hourCharge DOUBLE(8),
    totalCharge DOUBLE(8),
    PRIMARY KEY (empNo, jobClass),
    FOREIGN KEY (empNo) REFERENCES employee (empNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (jobClass) REFERENCES job (jobClass)
);
```

and this is the whole table command.

```
DROP database IF EXISTS projects;

CREATE database projects;

USE projects;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee;

CREATE TABLE employee(
    empNo INT(3) not null,
    empName VARCHAR(25) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (empNo)
);

CREATE TABLE project(
    projNo INT(2) not null,
    projName VARCHAR(25) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (projNo)
);

CREATE TABLE job(
    jobClass VARCHAR(4) not null,
    jobDesc VARCHAR(25) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (jobClass)
);

CREATE TABLE projectInfo(
    empNo INT(3) not null,
    projNo INT(2) not null,
    hourBill DOUBLE(4),
    projectLeader INT(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (empNo, projNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (empNo) REFERENCES employee (empNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (projNo) REFERENCES project (projNo)
);


CREATE TABLE workInfo(
    empNo INT(3) not null,
    jobClass VARCHAR(4) not null,
    hourCharge DOUBLE(8),
    totalCharge DOUBLE(8),
    PRIMARY KEY (empNo, jobClass),
    FOREIGN KEY (empNo) REFERENCES employee (empNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (jobClass) REFERENCES job (jobClass)
);
```

if anyone has any idea plz help me.
thanks! :)

Comment: try DOUBLE(4,2)

Comment: Thank you! this was the problem!!

Comment: Welcome.. . . . .  :-)